# Bitnami Ghost keeps redirecting to 127.0.0.1, but only on mobile

Tags: redirect, bitnami, ghost-blog

I installed, through AWS, a Bitnami Ghost instance.

I set up everything fine, got SSL working but, when going to the homepage on mobile, I get redirected to 127.0.0.1

This only happens on mobile devices, and on the homepage. Everything else works fine.

This is the content of my config.production.js:

```
{
  "url": "https://joaodesousa.com",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "bn_ghost",
      "password": "`xxxxxx",
      "database": "bitnami_ghost"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file"
    ]
  },
  "process": "local",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs/content"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something, because it only happens on mobile.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: I used a fresh instance. Did you change any other parameter in the application?

Comment: I have read somewhere else to set x-forwarded-proto header . I am also facing this issue, does somebody know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; this line can make the magic.

Can you try this in nginx config file:

server {

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name yourblog.com www.yourblog.com;
# SSL STUFF

location / {
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host    $http_host;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}